# MVC menu that will also work with ASP WebForms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu

We have been happily using the ASPExpert Menu control at work.  Recently I have received the green light to update a portion of the site to use MVC.  In doing so, I have to maintain the look and feel of the existing site on to the newer MVC portion of the site...  This includes the menu.  Unfortunately, it looks like ASPExpert Menu is dependent upon the __doPostBack() method and/or some other part of the legacy WebForms framework.  That said, I went back and received the green light to update the menu system over the entire site.  Therefore, here are the criteria:

1. Must work with WebForms and MVC
2. Must be customizable enough to change colors and sizes
3. Must be either open source or source available for purchase

I started looking at jQuery plug-ins, as this would not disrupt the WebForms and would also work with MVC, however there is a ton of them.

That said, the question is:

Have you used any good CSS/MVC/jQuery menu controls/helpers/plugins that also meet the above criteria in your web apps?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

-Jessy Houle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track by using jQuery to try and integrate the two.

I've been using the jQuery plugin, [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).  It was the easiest for me to set up and integrate in to my mvc project.  I'm sure it will work under WebForms as well.